# What's the best way to avoid code duplication in these two functions that do the same thing?

Tags: jquery, code-duplication, redundancy

**Given this form (which contains a submit button):**

```
<form id="review_form">
  <input type="submit" id="btn_submit" value="Submit with ajax! (submit button)">
</form>
```

**and this link (to submit the same form):**

```
<a href="#" id="lnk_submit">Submit with ajax! (hyperlink)</a>
```

In the following jQuery code, when the `#btn_submit` element is clicked, the form (`#review_form)` is submitted with ajax:

```
jQuery.fn.submitWithAjax = function() {
  this.submit(function() {
    $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), null, "script");
    return false;
  })
  return this;
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn_submit").submitWithAjax();
})
```

**What I want to do is remove the submit button and submit the form using the link above** (`#lnk_submit`) something like this:

```
$("#lnk_submit").click(function(){ 
   $("#review_form").submit(function() {
    $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), null, "script");
    return false;
    }); 
   return false;
});
```

But the problem is that **this duplicates all of the code in** `jQuery.fn.submitWithAjax` defined above.

*What's the best way to avoid the code duplication here?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about you have a function like this:

```
function submitWithAjax() {
    $("#review_form").submit(function() {
        $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), null, "script");
        return false;
    });         
}
```

And then link both actions to the function:

```
$(document).ready(submitWithAjax);
$("#lnk_submit").click(submitWithAjax);
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm oversimplifying, but can't you just assign the function to a variable, and reuse that?

```
var submitWithAjaxFn = function() {
  this.submit(function() {
    $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), null, "script");
    return false;
  })
  return this;
};

jQuery.fn.submitWithAjax = submitWithAjaxFn;
$("#lnk_submit").click(function(){ 
   $("#review_form").submit(submitWithAjaxFn); 
   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest answer (though maybe not most elegant) is to use the second function for both (which explicitly refers to your form independent of what is calling the function), and then give each 'trigger' the same class and attach the click event to both.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same functionality out of the hyperlink, make the action of the hyperlink simply a click of the button.

```
$('#lnk_submit').click(function(e){ $('#btn_submit').click(); return false; });
```